# Graph datastore: Caching graph datastructure with 200k vertex and edges

Tags: oracle, caching, graph, orientdb, oracle12c

I would like to create a graph data structure which represent a network of an area, as there can be multiple such graph, as cache need more runtime memory, I would like to hold the graph data structures in a graph data stores instead of a Cache (most likely orientdb). Is there any best way to handle graph.
The database which we use is Oracle 12c, I don't want to read data from oracle and create a graph data structure every time.

For the first hit for a area network, I will create a graph and hold it, until the area is processed completely.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain it better? Thx

Comment: The network data is in RDBMS, I would like to run graph algorithms to find out shortest path ,connectivity, etc.  Hence I need to create a graph data structure out of RDBMS. Creating graph is taking more time if the number of records is more.We are creating same graph for multiple times as the user wants work again on the same network after some days. i.e we are having the graph in runtime memory, once he logoff we are removing it from memory, I don't want to remove but to persist it.

Comment: Please don't post information in the comments. Use the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a doc with the code and a video example. Good luck
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ozi6ukmuj11nzam/AABEOG2MCQQOJGGktOiVkJaIa?dl=0